# scikit-image RAG mergine leaves black areas

Tags: python, scikit-image

[Following this example on the scikit-image homepage](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_rag_merge.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-segmentation-plot-rag-merge-py), in my example the image has some black areas after merging the RAG in case the threshold is set too high. From the documentation I understand that "similiar" regions should be merged, however it seems that some RAG regions are removed altogether. I'm wondering what the issue here might be, since for my applications it would be nice to segment many regions with SLIC (to get more structural details) and afterwards combine to bigger regions.

Here is my full script:

```
import click
import numpy as np
import skimage as ski
from PIL import Image


def _weight_mean_color(graph, src, dst, n):
    diff = graph.nodes[dst]["mean color"] - graph.nodes[n]["mean color"]
    diff = np.linalg.norm(diff)
    return {"weight": diff}


def merge_mean_color(graph, src, dst):
    graph.nodes[dst]["total color"] += graph.nodes[src]["total color"]
    graph.nodes[dst]["pixel count"] += graph.nodes[src]["pixel count"]
    graph.nodes[dst]["mean color"] = (
        graph.nodes[dst]["total color"] / graph.nodes[dst]["pixel count"]
    )


@click.command()
@click.version_option()
@click.option(
    "--path",
    type=str,
    required=True,
    help="path to an image",
)
def main(path: str) -> None:
    print(f"loading image {path}")
    pil_img = Image.open(path)
    # pil_img = pil_img.resize((pil_img.size[0] // 4, pil_img.size[1] // 4)) # downsize during testing to reduce waiting times
    input_image = np.asarray(pil_img)

    print("making slic")
    slic = ski.segmentation.slic(
        image=input_image, n_segments=5000, compactness=0.1, sigma=0.95, slic_zero=True
    )
    slic_rgb = ski.util.img_as_ubyte(
        ski.color.label2rgb(label=slic, image=input_image, kind="avg")
    )
    result = Image.fromarray(slic_rgb)
    result.save("results/slic_rgb.png")

    print("making rag")
    rag = ski.graph.rag_mean_color(input_image, slic)
    rag_thresh_cut = ski.graph.merge_hierarchical(
        labels=slic,
        rag=rag,
        thresh=32, # no issues here with a lower thresh, e.g.8
        rag_copy=False,
        in_place_merge=True,
        merge_func=merge_mean_color,
        weight_func=_weight_mean_color,
    )
    rag_rgb = ski.color.label2rgb(rag_thresh_cut, slic_rgb, kind="avg")
    result = Image.fromarray(rag_rgb)
    result.save("results/rag_rgb.png")
```

For example, here is a section of the original segmented image (slic segmentation)

[image]

And here the resulting image after merging the RAG (note the black area on the top-center)

[image]

**EDIT**

I have found at least part of the problem. In the code above `rag_thresh_cut` contains the label `0` for one color which is interpreted as background color by `skimage.color.label2rgb()`. In my case background color was set to black, if I set it to red for example, the area in the image above becomes red. A simple workaround for now is to simply add `1` to `rag_thresh_cut`, but I am still wondering how to best avoid this problem in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the functions across scikit-image are not consistent regarding whether 0 is considered background or not, which is why you are seeing this problem. Your workaround of adding 1 to either the result or the original SLIC output is currently the best possible answer, I think.